# apache camel - mock a remote endpoint on unit test

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, mockito

I have this on my RouteBuilder class:

```
 from("aws-s3://bucketName?amazonS3Client=#client")
                .to("direct:newEndpoint");
```

How can I unit test this, given that a unit test shouldn't use remote/external services?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Read the testing documentation at

- http://camel.apache.org/testing

And read about the advice with

- http://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html

And see the replaceFromWith(uri) how you can replace the from with some other endpoint.

Comment: Say, after I replace the uri (aws-s3:) to a mock uri (mock:), how will I be able to say that there are files in my mock (just like how there are files in my s3 bucket)?

Comment: you need to use a seda endpoint or somethink that has an in-memory queue. Then you can use the producer template to send messages to this seda endpoint, which your route will then pickup and route.

Comment: Seems `context.getRouteDefinitions()` from the doc is deprecated. How to use `AdviceWith` now?

Comment: Found solution here, http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Intercepting-documentation-old-adviceWith-deprecated-in-favour-of-td5711952.html, but "adviceWith" is still deprecated.